# Have same radio group input located on two different location of same form

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

Is there some way to locate in two different locations the same radio group inputs and if they change one of them, also the other changes automatically?

For two location, I mean two different places on a same submit form.

I edited the post to better show what I mean. There are two groups. If user click on 1 on first group, I'd like to have also 1 checked on second group.

My code:

```html
    <p>First group</p>
      <label class="n_people radio-inline">1
        <input type="radio" name="number_people" value="1">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="n_people radio-inline">2
        <input type="radio" name="number_people" value="2">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="n_people radio-inline">3
        <input type="radio" name="number_people" value="3">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="n_people radio-inline">4
        <input type="radio" name="number_people" value="4" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>           
      <br>

    <p>Second group</p>
      <label class="n_people radio-inline">1
        <input type="radio" name="number_people_2" value="1">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="n_people radio-inline">2
        <input type="radio" name="number_people_2" value="2">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="n_people radio-inline">3
        <input type="radio" name="number_people_2" value="3">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
      <label class="n_people radio-inline">4
        <input type="radio" name="number_people_2" value="4" checked="checked">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
      </label>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "two different locations"?

Comment: Thanks for comment. For two location, I meand two different places on a submit form.

Comment: Yes, it's possible but they should have the same name.

Comment: I edited the original post, to put the same name. You can run code snippet to see that doesn't work.

Comment: It works fine, there is only one radio button can be selected in the all eight radios.

Comment: Doesn't work fine. I edited the post to better show what I mean. There are two groups. If user click on 1 on first group, I'd like to have also 1 checked on second group.

Comment: I suspect you want the two sets of 4 to update depending on whether the user has selected the equivalent button in the other set. Is that right? I think you’ll need some JS.

Comment: @A Haworth you're right

Comment: @James, may I misunderstand you from the start, I think that I got your point, I added an answer please check.

Comment: just wanted to add that if you used a framework like react or vue it would be very much easier since you'd only need a v-model in vue to link them with each other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can divide the groups to two groups with wrapper `div`, and with event delegate, you can capture `change` event on each group, and change check the corresponding `radio` in the other group.

```js
const groupOne = document.getElementById('group-one')
const groupTwo = document.getElementById('group-two')

const changeGroup = (groupA, groupB) => {
    groupA.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
        groupB.querySelector(`[value="${e.target.value}"]`).checked = true
    })
}

changeGroup(groupOne, groupTwo)
changeGroup(groupTwo, groupOne)
```

```html
        <div id="group-one">
            <p>First group</p>
            <label class="n_people radio-inline"
                >1
                <input type="radio" name="number_people" value="1" />
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="n_people radio-inline"
                >2
                <input type="radio" name="number_people" value="2" />
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="n_people radio-inline"
                >3
                <input type="radio" name="number_people" value="3" />
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="n_people radio-inline"
                >4
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="number_people"
                    value="4"
                    checked="checked"
                />
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
        <br />
        <div id="group-two">
            <p>Second group</p>
            <label class="n_people radio-inline"
                >1
                <input type="radio" name="number_people2" value="1" />
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="n_people radio-inline"
                >2
                <input type="radio" name="number_people2" value="2" />
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="n_people radio-inline"
                >3
                <input type="radio" name="number_people2" value="3" />
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
            <label class="n_people radio-inline"
                >4
                <input
                    type="radio"
                    name="number_people2"
                    value="4"
                    checked="checked"
                />
                <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label>
        </div>
```